# jQuery ajax success conditional..?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm running the following php script through AJAX and need to integrate some error management into it:

```
$exists = file_exists('../temp/' . $email . '/index.html');
if($exists) {
    echo "ERROR!!!";
} else {
    createUserDirectory($email);
}
```

In the AJAX success function, how can I determine whether the script ran successfully or produced an error?

If it returns OK, I want to perform the redirect as it is at the moment, but if there's an error, I want to instead add the error to a DIV within the document (and not redirect of course...).

```
    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: 'generate/build.php',
           data: $("#generateStart").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
           success: function(data)
           {
              window.location.href="generate-site.php?user=" + data.replace(/^ +/,"") + ""; // Redirect to publish.php and remove any spaces from the URL (bug fix).
           }
         });
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can't you check the contents of `data`? You can also return your result as json, and include a `status` property (like: "ok"/"error"), or an `error` property (only if there's an error), and check those.

Comment: @ori - This seems like an ideal method. Could you perhaps put this in an answer with a little more guidance on how to return the result as JSON and then access that within the success handler and then I can accept it. Thanks.

Comment: I would, but I think @wsanville's answer is better. Why not use http status codes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your PHP script should return a `4xx` or `5xx` [HTTP status code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) to indicate failure. Then, the `error` method of [jQuery's ajax object](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) will be called.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `success` handler, check `if(data == 'ERROR!!!')`.

Comment: I thought of doing it this way but "ERROR!!!" is only temporary and the actual errors are going to be much longer than this meaning things will get a little sloppy..

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to add two parts to this: an error callback on the $.ajax function to see if the request failed on the net and then a check on the return value to see if it failed server validation (if a file exists in this case).

Example:

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    success : function(data) {
         if(data && data != "ERROR!!!") {
             //redirect
         }
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
         //Log error, display feedback to user, etc...
    }
);
```